# AnyLogic external RESTful API call

Tags: anylogic

is there any way to call an external web API from the AnyLogic modelling tool? I'd like to communicate with specific backend on some actions running during the simulation, so it would be cool.
Thanks a lot in advance,
Liudmila

Comment: If you can call it from Java, you can call it from AnyLogic. Note though, that you can only call external servers from the AnyLogic cloud IFF you have an active subscription. Else, run from AnyLogic IDE or compiled Java App

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i guess so, but i can't find how to do it, even some comprehencive example of creating custom function. How can i add a libraries to handle the rest calls such as JAX RS Client API or any other. Is it possible to do using the Educational version or only the professional one? Is there any examples or video of using it? i found a bunch of video explaining the function creation, but hey are all about the complex manipulation of the standard classes and methods already existing in the modelling framework. Could u give me a hint? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Google: "anylogic how to add java library" --> first link.